# issue with ipaddr filter to filter mac adress

Tags: python, linux, networking, ansible, redhat

I would check the entered mac_address syntax with the **ipaddr filter** which requires netaddr python package to use it.
The netaddr is already installed in my controller
`Requirement already satisfied: netaddr in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.7.19)`

but when i run the playbook this what i get

```
---
  - name: test MAC address manipulation
    hosts: all
    strategy: free
    gather_facts: no
    connection: local
    no_log: false

    # vars_prompt:
      # - name: "macaddress"
        # prompt: "mac address?"
        # private: no

    vars:
      macaddress: "1a-2b-3c-4d-5e-6f"

    tasks:
      - name: display all the formats
        ignore_errors: true
        debug:
           msg:
             - Original = {{ macaddress  }}
             - ""
             - "{ macaddress | ansible.utils.hwaddr('bool') }        = {{ macaddress | ansible.utils.hwaddr('bool') }}"
```

> Playbook execution

```
*
fatal: [Control]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The hwaddr filter requires python's netaddr be installed on the ansible controller"}
...ignoring
fatal: [Ansible1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The hwaddr filter requires python's netaddr be installed on the ansible controller"}
...ignoring
fatal: [Ansible2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The hwaddr filter requires python's netaddr be installed on the ansible controller"}
...ignoring
fatal: [Tower]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The hwaddr filter requires python's netaddr be installed on the ansible controller"}
...ignoring
fatal: [ansible3]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The hwaddr filter requires python's netaddr be installed on the ansible controller"}
...ignoring
fatal: [Ubuntu]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The hwaddr filter requires python's netaddr be installed on the ansible controller"}
...ignoring

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************
Ansible1                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1
Ansible2                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1
Control                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1
Tower                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1
Ubuntu                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1
ansible3                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1
```

this is the ansible and python version

```
ansible [core 2.12.5]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/x/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.12 (default, Sep 21 2021, 00:10:52) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-3)]
  jinja version = 2.10.3
  libyaml = True
```

Comment: Hi medisamm welcome to SO. That problem is caused by the same thing that [always causes it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bansible%5D+%22installed%22+%22on+the+ansible+controller%22): you're using the wrong `ansible_python_interpreter`

Comment: @mdaniel not quite this time IMO as the python module for the filter needs to be on the controller (not the target).

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the result of `ansible --version`? While you're at it read the output and check that the python version used by the ansible command is the same as the one you installed `netaddr` in. If they are different, either install the python module inside the correct version or reinstall ansible in the correct python version.

Comment: @Zeitounator i added the ansible --version exactly there is a difference between them

Comment: @Zeitounator what is the cleanest way to install the python module inside the correct version or reinstall ansible in the correct python version?

Comment: `<your_python_binary_displayed_for_ansible> -m pip install netaddr`

Answer (score -1):

You have netaddr installed on your controller in python3.6 libs but your Ansible is using python3.8.

```
     python3.8 -m pip install netaddr
```

Or use a virtualenv.